# Is there a max size for saving openEXR multilayer files?

Tags: file-format

I have a file that has many different render layers. I'm rendering at quite a high resolution, so the combined information I want to save is quite a lot. Blender gives an error when trying to save a OpenEXR Multilayer file. I tried saving a test file, and I was able to save one, so the only difference I can think of between when it works and when it comes up with an error is that that I am trying to save is too large. 
If there is a max size, or a maximum number of render layers, what is it?
Thanks.

Comment: I can save a regular OpenEXR file, but then I can't use other render passes, like AO or normals.

Comment: Please include the error message. Your issue is most likely caused by the system running out of memory.

Comment: It simply says 'Error: Could not write image C:\....filename.exr' It doesn't matter where I try to save the file either, it always tries to save it in a certain file directory (under my blendfiles folder)

Comment: @Benjimank Is there any more detailed info in the [console/terminal](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Console_window)?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a limit. In my experience **EXR Multilayer Feature** works really great in Blender. Make sure that:

- you have **file permissions to write** on your drive,
- it is not **a compositor issue** or
- you are **not running out of memory**.

I once rendered an image which needs to be a 30K EXR Multilayer with all possible passes included, **file size was about 12gb**. Rendering and Saving as EXR works as expected, but finally the **image resolution was to high for the current compositor (2.71) so I can't do the compositing in blender**. That's why I suggest you to **disable all post processing image operations** for the rendering process.

For rendering EXRs with Cycles [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/how-to-render-a-30k-image-with-cycles) is also helpful. In this post Brecht even mentioned that rendering EXRs is the only way to write and render the image at the same time. With that in mind it even makes sense to render as EXR for large filesize images.