# How to render a 30K image with cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, .exr

I have to render an image of 27000 x 7000 for a 150dpi print. The scene is quite big, but cycles preview and a render in 2700x7000 works as expected.

**If I hit render my memory raises up to 20gb, but my cpu usage is at 5%. Why cycles does not using the full cpu power during the render process?**

Here are my rendersettings:

```
Pathtracing
Samples:3000
Tilesize: 64x64
Bounces: Max 12 | Min 3
Diffuse: 4
Glossy: 4
Transmission: 12
Volume: 1
```

**Is there a way to optimize things?**

Comment: Are you reading the 5% cpu when it is rendering, or just starting, during the *Building BVH*?

Comment: After building bvh, when the image is rendering the task manager says: 5% cpu usage. In the last 20 hours cycles has rendered 269 of 26311 tiles at 4-6%.

Comment: Odd.. I tried this too, rendering the default cube at 27000x7000 my cpu stayed around ~50% (waffling around a bit). At 2700x700, my cpu was glued to 100%.

Comment: Commandline rendering seems to work (100% cpu usage at the moment).

Comment: I had a similar situation and realized the rendering was happening mostly on the GPU, leaving the CPU at limited usage: see here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/187901/102048

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With very large image resolutions Blender can run out of RAM. The operating system will then start using the hard disk for memory which is slow and will cause low CPU usage (swapping).

To reduce memory usage for very high resolution renders:

- Enable **Save Buffers** in the Performance panel so Blender does not keep the full render in memory during render
- Render from the **command line** so no display buffer must be kept in memory
- Output to an **OpenEXR** file so one tile can be written at a time

Comment: In my test I still had over half my ram free.. Blender used 1.5GB out of 15.7GB total. CPU usage was at 100% while building BVH and preparing, but dropped to about 20% once rendering started and stayed between 20% and 50% for about a minute, at which point I stopped it. Rendering from the CLI worked fine.

Comment: I also have swap disabled.

Comment: Displaying a very large image is probably a bottleneck too, which could be avoided by hiding the image editor that is showing the render result. In any case, the command line will have the least memory and CPU overhead.

Comment: Makes sense.. Though I still don't see why drawing the huge image would cause less CPU usage.. Wouldn't the CPU still chug along as fast as it can, just put not quite as much effort on path tracing and slightly more effort on (communicating with the GPU?) to draw the image?

Comment: Ideally yes, but threads may need to wait writing to the render buffer while the display thread is drawing it.

Comment: Also, such problems would be worst when rendering a default cube, on a complex scene and using 64x64 tiles CPU usage will probably be higher.