# how to render without displaying the rendering process

Tags: rendering

Im starting with Blender and I would like to know if its possible to render an animation without Blender showing each frame while rendering as I think this could slow down the process a bit. Am I right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome horacius :) You are right, for a complete solution see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16261/3710

Comment: Is `Alt+A` what you are looking for? If you want to lock the view to camera while playing, you can use `Numpad 0`.

Answer (score 3):

If your concern is performance, render using the **Command line**. This is for sure the most efficient way to render, since blender will not use any resources on the user interface.

The basic command is:

```
blender -b file.blend -x 1 -o //render -a
```

**-b**

Render in the background with no user interface

**file.blend**

The path to the blend file you want to render

**-x [0\1]**

Set option to add the file extension (e.g. "avi" "jpg", "png" etc) to the end of the file, 0 means no and 1 means yes

**-o**

Path for the output file and file name (// if using relative paths)

**-a**

Render the whole animation from start to end using all the settings saved in the blend file.

There are a lot more options accessible when rendering using the command line. More info [Here](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/command_line.html?highlight=command%20line) and [Here](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html).

---

If you want to use blender normally, you can close all UV/Image editor windows and in the the Properties window set Scene->Render->[Display](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/display.html?highlight=render%20display) to

> **Keep UI**
>
> The image is rendered to the Image Editor, but the UI remains the same. You will need to open the Image Editor manually to see the render result.

[image]

Comment: is it possible that in 2.79b this does not work? I've set it to "Keep UI" and it still shows preview rendering each small tile...

Comment: Blender settings always like guessing passwords, or run out of a maze.