# Why is Blender just using 54% of my CPU when rendering in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, workflow, performance, windows

Blender is only utilizing 54% on every core of my CPU (as shown in *TaskManager*) when rendering in Cycles. How can I make it use 100%?

Can this be fixed within Blender or is it more of an OS/hardware-related issue?

Comment: Using 54% doing what exactly? Blender can use more or less resources depending if it is a multi-tasked operation or not. Rendering for example is multi tasked and can use multiple processors, but certain mesh operations for example are not. Please edit your question and provide more information.

Comment: When rendering it can use 100%, but for almost all other things it uses just 1 or 2 cores (there are exceptions and some things are indeed multi-threaded). Compared with other 3D apps and not counting rendering I would put Blender in some bottom place performance-wise. Fortunately the performance is getting better and better with every release as things are being optimized by devs.

Comment: Please include OS information as well. On Linux 100% CPU means one CPU running at 100%, so the max of your machine would be 1000%. On Windows a single CPU at max would be 10%, with the entire machine at max at 100%. Kind of makes a difference.

Comment: In Properties -> Render -> Performance, is "threads" set to "Auto-Detect"? Maybe try to set it to "fixed" and play with number of treads manually?

Comment: I have uppdated the text

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16251/3710

Comment: It is posible that I have a powerlimit that make the CPU drop its clock speed, I have a new PSU on its way.

Comment: Since the answer given has recieved 3 UP votes, will the people who downvoted the question upvote the question so that the question is not stuck in a negative vote state? I don't quite understand the downvoting of questions system. The question is valid enough to recieve a valid answer, therefore it makes no sense that the question has a -3 voting amount. People on this site are very quick to downvote a questions, but not upvote it. This discussion has been made so often.

Comment: @TTTTTTa You would understand if you saw the revision history. Click on the edited by so and so...and look at the original. When it gets updated, there is nothing in BSE that alerts others of it, and those who voted it down don't come back. Meanwhile, if it got voted down before editing, it is not likely to be voted back up later by others just up voting it. Hope that helps to clarify :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, now I can understand this better. I was not trying to cause a stir, the only reason I brought it up is because I was having the same question as the OP and I think the answers given here are very good. I'm fairly new to BSE, so it is somewhat confusing to new people on the forum to see a question with -3 votes, but yet was able to be answered well by someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check max CPU usage in windows advance power options. In there set the maximum CPU usage to 100.

Comment: This is not an answer regarding Blender's side of the problem...the other answer is far better as this is just an OS specific, yet general with regard to various applications. Even though this may have fixed your problem (and the other didn't) answering this way makes your question off topic.

Comment: The other is a better answer if it wasn't for the even CPU distribution. If anyone did poste something that would have removed a nother bottleneck would I accept to make it the answer.

Comment: I edited your question to try to make this more reasonable. Please review/accept my edit if you are comfortable with it. The primary reason it was voted down AFAIK is because it was about specific hardware which is against BSE rules (that's at least why I voted it down). If you accept the edit, I'll change my vote accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Try to changing the number of threads to the same amount of the CPU (in this case 10)?

[image]

Comment: Shady Puck did remove the part of the question that say that it used 54% on every core so I whon't go test it. It do probebly work if it was on 100% on 5 threds and the other on 1%

Comment: I read the original question. regardless, you should try this solution anyway.