# Blender freezes when rendering,building the last samples

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Out of sudden the Blender freezes when rendering on Cycles.Always at the same moment.When the image is almost done,that is to say Path tracing title is done 135/135 and it's building up samples,at the last point it stops working.I made all the updates to mac OS and using the last 2.78a version,even though it started on 2.77

I thought it was the project's problem so I opened different project and it does the same thing.I'm completely stuck and unable to render anything.Sometimes it renders one frame but the following gets stuck again.
Is anyone else experiencing this? I have no idea what it could be?
Thanks so much for any help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the image you are trying to render exceeds the resources on your computer. Please [edit] your question and describe the complexity of your scene: are you using simulations? Particles? How many levels of subdivisions are you using on your object? what is the size of your textures? Are you rendering using CPU or GPU? what kind of graphics card are you using?  what is the sizeof the final image? Please also add images of your render settings. Please consider uploading the file for others to inspect.

Comment: Halo Cegaton,thank you for quick reply.I'm rendering on CPU with the normal texture size,some 1024x1024,some 2048x2048.the image is full hd 1920x1080.I'm rendering to  PNG frames but when I switch to other outputs like Tiff,Jpeg or QT it does the same thing.No simulations.no particles involved. Plus I have already rendered like 2 minutes of this project. I thought that it's the project's problem,maybe I clicked on something without knowing,but when I open any other project it does the same thing.Even when I only have a textured cube with simple animation it still freezes.I'm really lost here.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? Im suddenly experiencing the same. I can't render Files  anymore that rendered fine dozens of times just hours ago...

Answer (score 0):

For laptop users:

On any render, my computer (the whole screen) would freeze about 5 seconds, and after some seconds it would freeze again.

To fix, I had to go to File -> User Preferences -> System and on the bottom-left side I picked CUDA for the "Cycles Compute Device", and this fixed the problem.

[image: CUDA]

---

It seems very noob-ish because it actually is! And it worked for me since I am a beginner, I hope this helps another beginner searching this on Google.

Comment: See this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-cycles and this one for more https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65871/why-is-blender-just-using-54-of-my-cpu-when-rendering-in-cycles