# Blender states I'm "Out of memory" when trying to render, but I have tons of unused memory?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, memory-management

I'm having a recurring problem where Blender is refusing to render an image, stating I am out of memory, when I clearly have a huge amount of excess memory available. I'm attempting to render in cycles, optix, no denoising.

The scene is about 1.8 million polies, and a handful of 4k textures (less than 10). In the viewport it states it's using 4 GB of memory, and 6 GB of VRAM. While this sounds like a lot, I am running an RTX 3090 (24GB VRAM) and have 48 GB of system RAM. Is this a matter of Blender not supporting the card, or something else? I rendered much more complex scenes before getting the 3090 with zero issues.

Comment: I should also add that "peak" memory at fail, when trying to render, always says about 3800 MB. Nothing else significant is running on the PC.

Comment: Have you monitored the GPU memory to see if that's the culprit?

Comment: I have monitored while trying to render, and the GPU ram maxes out at about 9-10 GB during the render (which leaves another 14). And load maxes out at about 30%

Comment: Did you set a memory limit for textures or something like that?

Comment: No, I haven't changed any memory settings from default, is there somewhere I can raise that limit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Blender just using 54% of my CPU when rendering in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65871/why-is-blender-just-using-54-of-my-cpu-when-rendering-in-cycles)

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but I don't believe that question is the one.