# Baking the physics animation takes too long

Tags: animation, physics, baking

I am baking some curtain animation, i wonder why it does not use all of the hardware source avaible.
As i know it uses CPU to calculate Physics, looks like it does not use enough of the CPU. Is this a problem or this is how Blender works?
This screenshot taken while baking the animation:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Blender just using 54% of my CPU when rendering in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65871/why-is-blender-just-using-54-of-my-cpu-when-rendering-in-cycles)

Comment: No it's about cpu rendering. My problem is baking the cloth animation before render.

Comment: They are both computer process, the link is about configuring your O (windows) to make you process use as much as they need from your hardware