# Render time increasing drastically towards the end of the render

Tags: rendering

I apologize in advance if I didn't manage to utilize the search function to its fullest.

I am through my first single frame scene render during which I had several iterations of previews and trial renders. I've tried various settings for the Cycles GPU renderer (experimental mode for the adaptive sub divs), path tracing.

The issue is that when I started the final render the estimated time to finish was 2.5 hours, which seemed OK to me.
But in real life, the estimation timer practically stopped on the last 10% of the render, the CPU usage went from ~100% to 50%, the GPU usage went to 0%. The total time it took to render was 8 hours.

Anybody had a similar issue? Is there a way to avoid this dreadful phenomenon?

Thank you!

Comment: Did the scene complexity increase towards the end?

Comment: A few tips: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16261/31447

Comment: No, Scene complexity does not increase towards the end.

Comment: @brockmann I tried turning on the OPENEXR option - I supposed I should see a file being written to in the "output folder" during the render - Is that so? any special settings to change ?

Comment: Yep, of course. Usually "/tmp" @user69320

Comment: @brockmann do changing directory from "/tmp" to any other directory affects the render time?

Comment: Why it should? @Yash

Comment: You said change directory to /tmp and..?

Comment: I didn't say anything like that @Yash.