# Why can't I render 16K? (Cycles crash)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to render an image at 16K resolution (15360 × 8640) but Blender (version 2.81) keeps crashing after rendering a few tiles. 4K animation (over 5 hours rendering) and 8K static images render just fine without crashes.

Both CPU and GPU render mode has the same behavior (I'm in supported feature set). I thought it was maybe a ram problem but the scene is about 3gb and I have 32GB of RAM installed.

Does anyone have a clue what the problem might be?

Comment: Suggest try rendering to exr, enable save buffers and use the command line: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16261/3710

Comment: You are probably  in  a situation where your scene exceeds the resources/computing-power  available. 16K is 4 times the size of 8k.

Comment: @p2or thank you that actually worked for me!

Comment: Glad I could help @systemprintln

Answer (score -1):

I'll have the same problem with a small 200mb scene. If I use more than, say 200 samples, then the scene will crash. If it actually was a memory problem, then Blender would give you the error: *Out of memory*. A few things I have uncovered that help me with this is *using less samples*, *denoising*, and using smaller size tiles for rendering. (CPU). Using larger tiles for your GPU may also work. Blender will also crash if your CPU is slower than the minimum speed for processing a huge render. One last thing that might help is to use more CPU threads. More threads will use more of the CPU, so that more of the CPU is used for rendering. This may help Blender to not crash. I compared rendering a scene on one thread as opposed to 250, and there was a big difference. The downside to using more threads is that the rest of your computer may run slower. These are just some options for rendering, but I hope at least a few help.