# Why is rendering with cpu added only mildly faster even though it uses so much more power?

Tags: rendering

I get 3 seconds faster rendering rate when using optix with cpu but when I render without it is about as fast. I can render 4-5 project really fast at the same time when cpu is turned off when cpu is on there is no difference and sometimes the render times are substantially longer then just using GPU making matters worse rendering a second file at the same time is mildly possible or just straight up impossible when adding the cpu.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't given your hardware, but it's possible your CPU just doesn't have that much to add by comparison.

There is still some CPU load when doing a GPU render, so everything leftover is what you have to dedicate to additional CPU rendering.  Your GPU has dedicated silicon to do significant portions of the math involved with rendering, and that's what typically makes it render tiles much faster, then it hands the rest off to the CPU.

A couple of things:  If you're using large tiles, CPUs have trouble handling those.  Enable the Auto Tile Size addon, and it should find a good compromise for hybrid rendering.

You can also try rendering through command line, I've heard this reduces load on the system because you're not constantly integrating and redrawing the image for the render tab.

Comment: True, https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16261/

Comment: The only problem is my GPU only uses 20% at max rather then the whole GPU aswell